# How to use native transitions in Cordova?

Tags: cordova, html-framework-7

Is there any robust plugin available to handle transitions as smooth as native in Cordova apps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

see this [Link](https://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/native-page-transitions#VersionHistory) Native Page Transitions

Comment: Actually I am using this and it works very good but how to make this work for any transition not only page transition?

Comment: And in F7 when I am sliding to href: "about.html" (for example) it doesnt work, do you know whats the correct syntax for this?

Comment: @Raz to slide href `window.plugins.nativepagetransitions.slide({
    // the defaults for direction, duration, etc are all fine
    "href" : "next.html"
});`

Comment: Yes, with AngularJS Ive tried this and it worked but with F7 (v1) somewhy it just goes to homepage everytime.. and btw, ussualy I am linking to another page with: <a href="next.html"> and it works fine.

Comment: @Raz i never worked whit F7 cant help whit that sorry